# elk's elastic search dsl case sensitive

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, case-sensitive, elk

I'm doing an Elasticsearch Query DSL query on ELK such as:

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "url.path": {
        "value": "*download*",
        "boost": 1,
        "rewrite": "constant_score"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but it seems is case sensitive (so show only info with "download", not "Download" or "DOWNLOAD").
i.e. is case sensitive.

can I disable this? and search case insensitive?

**Version used: 7.9.1**

Answer (score 1):

The below query will help you perform **case-insensitive** search  as it will fetch results for `*download`, `*Download` and `*DOWNLOAD`. You may replace  with your index and  with the field you would like to perform this search.

**Search Query**

```
   GET /<my-index>/_search
    {
     "query" : {
         "bool" : {
            "must" : {
               "query_string" : {
                   "query" : "*download",
                   "fields": ["<field1>"]
               }
            }
         }
     }
}
```

If you wish to perform the same search on multiple fields, you can add the same in list.

**Search on multiple fields**

```
GET /<my-index>/_search
    {
     "query" : {
         "bool" : {
            "must" : {
               "query_string" : {
                   "query" : "*download",
                   "fields": ["<field1>","<field2>","field3>"]
               }
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Nope. If I search "*download*" or "*Download*" it gives to me two different result sets. I've used this `{
     "query" : {
         "bool" : {
            "must" : {
               "query_string" : {
                   "query" : "*Download*",
                   "fields": ["url.path"]
               }
            }
         }
     }
}`

Answer (score 1):

There is a `case_insensitive` parameter available for `wildcard` query, but it was introduced in Elasticsearch 7.10.0, so you need to upgrade if you are still on 7.9.1.

**If you can upgrade to 7.10.0 or higher:**

Ideally, in index mapping field should use `wildcard` type:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "url.path": {
        "type": "wildcard"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then a `wildcard` query with case insensitivity enabled will find all the variants ("download", "DOWNLOAD", "download", etc)

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "url.path": {
        "value": "*download*",
        "boost": 1,
        "rewrite": "constant_score",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**If you must remain at 7.9.1:**

Define your mapping in such a way that Elasticsearch treats the field contents as lowercase. The following will mimic wildcard type (it's a keyword, so only one token) indexed as lowercase.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "url": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "lowercase-keyword"
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "lowercase-keyword": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query, without the `case_insensitive` parameter which is unsupported in this version:

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "url": {
        "value": "*download*",
        "boost": 1,
        "rewrite": "constant_score"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example results (note that searching for `"*download*"` and `"*DoWnLoAd*"` with both work in the same way):

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 3,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my-index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "PtbQe3wByTvslqtrs7Cn",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "url": "http://example.com/download"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my-index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "P9bQe3wByTvslqtrvbDt",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "url": "http://example.com/Download"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my-index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "QNbQe3wByTvslqtrzbDw",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "url": "http://example.com/DOWNLOAD"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can use [`case_insensitive`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html#wildcard-query-field-params) parameter for wildcard query. This parameter was introduced in 7.10.0 version**

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "url": {
        "properties": {
          "path": {
            "type": "wildcard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "url":{
    "path":"xx/download"
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "url.path": {
        "value": "*Download*",
        "boost": 1,
        "rewrite": "constant_score",
         "case_insensitive": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

No results will be there when you are searching for `*Download*` or `*DOWNLOAD*`

**Update:**

You can use the wildcard query with `"case_insensitive": true` parameter

Adding a sample index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "url": {
    "path": "download"
  }
}
{
  "url": {
    "path": "DOWNLOAD"
  }
}
{
  "url": {
    "path": "Download"
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "url.path": {
        "value": "*DOWNLOAD*",
        "boost": 1,
        "rewrite": "constant_score",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67210888",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "url": {
            "path": "download"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67210888",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "url": {
            "path": "Download"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67210888",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "url": {
            "path": "DOWNLOAD"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I think user is asking for just the opposite. case_insensitive should be true

Comment: yes. But both doesn't works. I've 7.9.1. Any alternatives?

Comment: @markzzz if you want the result to be case insensitive, then I think your query should work. Can you please share some sample index data, which you are using ?

Comment: @markzzz any update here? If you are not getting the expected result, please share your sample index data, so that I can provide a working example for that

Comment: not sure how to share data. its within elk. I just place the wildcard, and nothing happens (i.e. it does error message)

Comment: @markzzz that means there is no index mapping also which you have configured?

Comment: i did configured nothing, just place the query you posted

Comment: @markzzz please go through the updated part of the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Nope. i can discriminate all the combinations. What if the content is "DoWnlOAd"? I need a one-written rule

Comment: @ESCoder case insensitive is not supported in this version, as already stated